# Use prepared statements in MySQL-PHP-Code

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-like

I'm a newbie so my question is maybe a little bit strange. I'm trying to use prepared statements for the following code:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/config.php');


$value = $_POST["value"];
$ort = $_GET["ort"];


$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Suchmaschine WHERE firma = :firma AND ort = :ort');
$stmt->execute(array('firma' => $value, 'ort' => $value));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {   
   echo "<a href=".$row['link'].">".$row['firma']."</a><br>";
}
?>
```

I tried some ways, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please add the code with the prepared statements that you can't get working.

Comment: You should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: `'ort' => $value` seems wrong

Comment: `'ort' => $ort` would be more likely

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help. Still no output. What can I do? I want to echo link and firma from all lines where column firma=$_POST["value"]; and column ort=$_GET["ort"];

Comment: How can I do this? Please help me.

Comment: I would print out the values of `$value` and `$ort` before the prepare-statement to see if they have some sensible values. I would also test the SQL-statement with direct connection to the database.

Comment: Cause I'm a newbie (and not english speaking, too) I don't really know, what you mean. Can you try to explain it to me or modify my code as you think?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly this line you are missing : and a wrong variable name, should be:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':firma' => $value, ':ort' => $ort));
```

Then you are not fetching the results.

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach( $results as $row ) {
        echo "<a href=".$row['link'].">".$row['firma']."</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';' in /var/www/username/html/folder/folder2/file.php on line 14

Comment: Thank you, no error now. But still an issue. E.g. there is the word "example" in my table. Search works if I search for "example". But I get no matches if I search for "exam" because not the whole word. Can you help me here too, please??

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on the followling line:

```
$stmt->execute(array('firma' => $value, 'ort' => $value));
```

should be changed to:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':firma' => $value, ':ort' => $value));
```

Please note the addition of the colons prepending the strings passed as the keys to the array passed to the execute statement.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: The colons in the placeholder names, in the `execute` or `bind` statements, are  optional.